# How do I round this input below to a whole number?

Tags: java

```java
Avg = ((int)2*avg1 + 3*focavg + 5*critrating / 10);
System.out.println("Overall movie rating: " + Avg);
```

I stored `Avg` as a double and the instructions want me to round the output of this code to a whole number but, it always comes out as a decimal.

The Code output: Overall movie rating: 82.57666666666667

Is there a way I can round this up to 83?

Comment: read about round(), floor() and ceil() functions

Comment: Please search on *something* before asking, and show the results from your efforts in your question.

Comment: double avg = 82.57666666666667;
int round = (int) Math.round(avg);

Answer (score 0):

You can try  importing "java.lang.Math" and can use ceiling method of Math class in print statement:
System.out.println("Overall movie rating: " + Math.ceil(Avg));